# How can I add an alternate racial trait to a race in PCGen?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, homebrew, racial-traits, pcgen

I'm trying to include some custom races into PCGen for simplicity (custom setting). I've got the races down, easy enough. The problem I can't figure out is how to add the alternate traits for a few of my races.

I want to add an alternate trait that I can select for the characters and NPCs of each race, like with subraces or something.

And I haven't really tried anything beyond adding the over-arching races, because I can't find the right file for where alternate traits would go. So I suppose the question is more where do I add these traits to the files than how do I add them?

Comment: Could you expand your question with an example of what you want to see, and what you have tried already to make it work? Thanks!

Comment: I have never used this program, but this might help: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/67234/how-can-i-add-a-trait-to-pcgen

Comment: @C Anderson Yeah, I found that while I was looking around. Problem is that's just for a general selectable trait, not one to replace the default racial. Eh, nevermind. It'll have to do, I'll just make the default selectable. Not like anyone else is gonna use this.

Comment: @Daraka this is quite a wide scope - have you tried taking a similar feature in an existing race, and tracing how that is implemented? For example, maybe take a look at a standard race (like Elf) in the Advanced Player's Guide?

Answer (score 3):

On [this YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fuiReDpK5k0) channel describing how to create races, this comment can be found for racial traits, assuming you're creating a "Dwelf":

```
Dwelf CATEGORY:Internal ABILITY:Special Ability|AUTOMATIC|TYPE=Dwelf Racial Trait.
```

I don't know if this syntax is still the used, but nevertheless I guess it's worth a try :)

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) if you haven't already, and check out the [help center](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help) for more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!